# Extending a DBT var in dbt_project.yml

Tags: yaml, jinja2, dbt

I have a variable defined in my `dbt_project.yml` file as a set. I want to extend this set by adding a single string element to it or in future potentially another set.
Here a template of what my `dbt_project.yml` currently looks like:

```
vars:
  var1_tuple: [item1, item2, item3] # existing set
  var2: '{{ (var('var1') + ['install']) | join(", ") }}'
```

Then in `table.sql`

```
WHERE column1 "{{ var('var2') }}"
```

But when I call this variable `var2` from the SQL code, the code breaks as it doesn't correctly parse the var as a SQL set but rather as a string.

How can I correctly parse `var2`?

Answer (score 0):

Jinja treats tuples differently: in order to append something into a tuple, you first need to convert it into an array. On the other hand, you should also set the value you want to append into an array.

So, the following should work:

```yaml
my_var: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
my_other_var: '{{ var("my_var") + ["item4"] }}'
```

From here, if you run something like:
`{% do log(var('my_other_var'), info=True) %}`

you should be seeing:
`['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']`

Comment: Thanks Aleix, one question though: in Jinja this works formatting as a tuple, but if I want to read it within a SQL statement as a SET, do I have any nice way to convert the formatting to SQL sets? Hence from square brackets to parenthesis? Or is it the wrong tool to achieve what I planned?

Comment: In that case, I believe you could just add `|join(", ")` at the end so get a SQL `set`. So it would look like `'{{ (var("my_var") + ["item4"]) | join(", ") }}'`. You should also then do something similar with the first variable

Comment: Hi Aleix, sorry for disturbing again. Somehow it doesn't like the format, because it puts the string letters ' ' before the SQL set: `line 27 at position 30 unexpected ''(reattribution, install_update, install)''`. But if I remove those string chars then it's not a YAML valid format.

Answer (score 0):

The vars context method can only be used in dbt_project.yml for variables passed in via the command line with `--vars`. See [this dbt help doc](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/dbt-project-yml-context) for details.

> The following context methods and variables are available when configuring resources in the dbt_project.yml file. This applies to the models:, seeds:, and snapshots: keys in the dbt_project.yml file.
>
> Available context methods:
>
> - env_var
> - var (Note: only variables defined with `--vars` are available)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to manipulate dependecies of the vars declared in the dbt_project.yml ; isn't possible there?