# Using dbt to Test that Table Continues to Get Larger Over Time

Tags: dbt

I'm currently using DBT for transformations from a large CSV file that's received every day that we load into our data warehouse. Unfortunately, the CSV file is sent to us by a vendor and they're unable to sent diffs so we get the full file every day (the file should never have rows deleted/only added). We had an issue recently where something happened on their end and the file we received somehow had rows deleted which caused downstream issues.

Is there a way in dbt to add a test that would make sure that a table always has has >= to the number of rows its had historically?

Comment: You can set up a pre-hook on your model that simply stores the timestamp + aggregation in a separate table, let the model run the update, then run a test against that after your model runs. The problem, of course, is that your table will already be updated at this point. Similarly, if you're using Snowflake, you can create a test that queries against the time travel version of the table.

If you want the job to fail, you can still use a pre-hook on the model with the CSV and have it run a call statement to do the comparison and use `{{ exceptions.raise_compiler_error() }}`  to fail the job.

Answer (score 0):

In dbt projects, creating a base table, such as `base_vendor__model`, is recommended for performing complex operations before staging your data.

To ensure consistency in your data flow, you can implement [a singular test](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/tests#singular-tests) that verify the new table consistently contains additional records.

An example test can be:

```sql
SELECT id 
FROM {{ref('base_vendor__model')}}
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM {{ref('stg_vendor_table')}})
```

This test will fail if any ID present in the staging table (your previous day's table) is absent in the base table (the recently fetched data).

Utilize the [dbt build](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/build) command to trigger the creation of a new model, like `stg_vendor__model.sql`, solely upon the successful completion of this test:

```sql
SELECT * FROM {{ ref('base_model_sql')}}
```

For more detailed information and best practices on structuring dbt projects, refer to [this resource](https://docs.getdbt.com/best-practices/how-we-structure/2-staging#staging-files-and-folders).

Comment: You can also check [dbt-audit-helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77329198/extending-a-dbt-var-in-dbt-project-yml)